# Is my simplified Boolean expression correct?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm trying to simplify the following Boolean expression:

A'(B'C'D' + BC'D' + BCD) + A(BC'D + BC'D + BCD + BCD' + B'C'D)

I've already made a few steps to simplify it, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or if I made any mistakes. Here's what I've done so far:

I combined the terms BCD and BC'D, which resulted in BCD + BC'D = B(C + C')D = BD.
I also combined the terms B'C'D' and BCD', which resulted in B'C'D' + BCD' = B'(C' + CD')D' = B'D'.

Then, I combined the terms BCD and B'D', which resulted in BCD + B'D' = B(C + C')(D + D') = B.

Finally, I combined the terms BD and B'D', which resulted in BD + B'D' = B(D + D') = B.
After these steps, I was left with the following expression:

A'(B + B'D') + A(B + B'D')

I'm not sure if I made any mistakes in my simplification process or if there are any further steps I can take to simplify this expression. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Your initial expression has BCD in both halves. What does this mean to you? Also apply that to your final simplified expression.

Comment: you have an error in your first expression ... it does not match the expression in the picture

Comment: draw a Karnaugh map

Comment: There is an error in your text rendition of the expression if the rendered image is definitive: It should read A'(B'C'D' + BC'D' + BCD) + A(BC' **D'**  + BC'D + BCD + BCD' + B'C'D)

Comment: `which resulted in BD + B'D' = B(C + C')(D + D') = B` That's unexpected (as is `BCD + B'D' = B(C + C')(D + D')`, but check the simpler one first).